# Post request data limit

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to send html content as text, to the server on a post request. But my request object is empty for content that is large. It works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE. 
Is there a limit specific to Chrome and IE for post request?

I have tried dividing the content into sub-strings and merging them in my jsp. Again this works in Mozilla and not in Chrome.

```
var myform = document.createElement('form');
document.body.appendChild(myform);
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('name','eyeframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
myform.setAttribute('action','renderAsPdf.jsp');
myform.setAttribute('method','post');
myform.setAttribute('target','eyeframe');
var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "htmlContent");
hiddenField.setAttribute("value", strHTML);
myform.appendChild(hiddenField);
myform.submit();
myform.remove();
```

I have also tried dividing the content into sub-strings and merging them in my jsp. Again this works in Mozilla and not in Chrome.
I cannot use ajax as I stream back a pdf from the jsp.

Comment: Any background to this issue - client/server code you could share?

Comment: Are sure the input hiddenField (htmlContent) gets appended to the form?

Comment: Yes, It works for smaller content

Comment: Would it work if you remove the last line (myform.remove();)? Just wondering.

Comment: no.. Just tried it. doesn't work :(